# Is there any point to raising Magic for Warrior or Rogue?

Tags: magic, dragon-age-rpg

If I don't want to take the Spirit Warrior or Templar specialization, is there any mechanical reason to increase Magic for a Warrior or Rogue?

- What non-spellcasting tests use Magic?
- Are there spells that target your Magic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes and no.

The usefulness of **Magic** is very limited if you do not learn any spells or abilities based on it.

But it's useful to resist effects caused by spells.

> Or if a mage cast a spell at you, you might have to
>   make a Magic test to **resist the effects**.

Example: The [Affliction Hex](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Affliction_Hex) spell (pg. 110) says:

> A primary target who makes a **successful Magic (Entropy) test against your Spellpower** suffers only a –1 penalty and completely negates the effects on the secondary targets. Secondary targets may also make **Magic (Entropy) resistance tests to negate their own penalties** entirely, but their individual successes or failures only affect themselves.

This means that **targets with higher Magic can resist the effects of spells easier.**

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. (except the link does not bring you to the tabletop RPG)

Comment: Yeah, but there is no open content document for the system. Sorry.